# rel properties in html tags

Tags: html, xhtml

I was reading about Google SEO suggestions and I had a question:

Can we write many Rel in the rel property??

How can we write many rel in it?With a blank space as my example that follows??

For example, something like this is ok?:

```
<a rel="noindex nofollow" href="/mysite.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

Thanks All in advance!!

Comment: Where did you find a suggestion to use `noindex` in a `rel` attribute?! It wouldn't make any sense at all for that to have any effect.

Comment: In addition to that, here's what you can use (in HTML5) within your `rel` attribute and what each type does: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes

Answer (score 4):

The W3c say at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel:

> This attribute describes the
>   relationship from the current document
>   to the anchor specified by the href
>   attribute. The value of this attribute
>   is a space-separated list of link
>   types.

So, yes, you can.